# add search ajax ability to this html form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am stuck trying to add some ajax search ability to this php form. The form is already working but since I have many outputs, I want users to be able to search and select a profile from there. I tried jquery tablesorter and although it works, it's not quite what I was looking for.

Hope someone can help. Thanks. Here is the form.

```
    <form action="<?php echo CRoute::getURI(); ?>" method="post" id="jomsForm" name="jomsForm" class="community-form-validate">
<div class="jsProfileType">
    <ul class="unstyled">
    <?php
        foreach($profileTypes as $profile)
        {
    ?>
        <li class="space-12">

            <label for="profile-<?php echo $profile->id;?>" class="radio">
                <input id="profile-<?php echo $profile->id;?>" type="radio" value="<?php echo $profile->id;?>" name="profileType" <?php echo $default == $profile->id ? ' disabled CHECKED' :'';?> />
              <strong class="bold"><?php echo $profile->name;?></strong>
            </label>
            <?php if( $profile->approvals ){?>
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_REQUIRE_APPROVAL');?></span>
            <?php } ?>

            <span class="help-block">
                <?php 
$profile->description = JHTML::_('content.prepare',$profile->description);  
echo $profile->description;?>
            </span>

            <?php if( $default == $profile->id ){?>
                    <em><?php echo JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_ALREADY_USING_THIS_PROFILE_TYPE');?></em>
            <?php } ?>



        </li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php if( (count($profileTypes) == 1 && $profileTypes[0]->id != $default) || count($profileTypes) > 1 ){?>
<div style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <?php if( $showNotice ){ ?>
    <span style="color: red;font-weight:700;"><?php echo JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_NOTE');?>:</span>
    <span><?php echo $message;?></span>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<table class="ccontentTable paramlist" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="paramlist_key" style="text-align:left">
            <div id="cwin-wait" style="display:none;"></div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary validateSubmit" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_NEXT'); ?>" name="submit">
        </td>
        <td class="paramlist_value">

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="gid" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" id="authenticate" name="authenticate" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" id="authkey" name="authkey" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). It's a really well done jquery-based library with easy-to-use ajax and custom-rendering features. You can check the `Loading Remote Data` section of the documentation.

It can be configured to fetch data from the server, after N chars have been inserted by the user. Then you simply have to implement the server-side search action and with very few code you've a working (and very good looking) ajax selector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Select2 really does seem like a possible solution but it also seems so complicated especially for novice like myself. Funny thing in coding is that even something that seems like such a small change can give the biggest headache!

As a walk through, am I to target searching through the form first or searching through the database and posting results to the form? Thanks.

Comment: There is a [PHP Example](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/wiki/PHP-Example) here. It's very rough, but gives you the idea.